# ASP.Net Identity - creating custom GenerateResetPasswordAsync of UserManager Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my own custom table of Users. And I want to override the GenerateResetPasswordAsycnc and VerifyResetPasswordTokenAsync of User Manager. What are the requirements to do this and how can I implement it.